# Electromagnetic Wave Impedance

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

In a derivation of the transmission and reflection coefficients for light incident at an angle onto a surface where we have a change in refractive indices the proof says that $$\frac{E}{H}=\frac{Z_0}{n}$$ in order to relate the boundary condition for the parallel continuity of $H$ to the equivalent expression for the parallel continuity of $E$.

I thought that $\frac{E}{H}$ was the impedance of free space so why does a factor of $n$ appear?

Comment: $n$ is the refractive index of the dielectric and so you have the characteristic impedance of the dielectric.

Comment: @goods $\mu = 1$